# Number of functions from $A$ to $A$

Tags: functions

We have the set $A=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$. what is the number of functions from $A$ to $A$?

I think the domain of the function should contain all the elements of $A$ but range of the function may have any elements of $A$ or not having them. so for each of the numbers from $1$ to $5$ we have two possibilities $(1)$ existing in the range of function. $(2)$ not existing in the range. so the number of functions from $A$ to $A$ is $2^5=32$. is my justification right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Let $X$ and $Y$ be finite sets. Then the set $Y^X$ is finite and $\#(Y^X) = (\#Y)^{\#X}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4011693/let-x-and-y-be-finite-sets-then-the-set-yx-is-finite-and-yx-y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you must take account of which element is mapping to which.

Each element of the domain can map to one of $5$ elements so the number of possible functions is $5^5$.